# Replace forEach and add with collect

Tags: java, for-loop, collections, lambda

How this can be replaced with collect?

```
List<Serializable> result = new ArrayList<>();
entries.forEach(entry-> result.add(session.save(entry)));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's pretty straight forward :

```
List<Serializable> result = 
    entries.stream()
           .map(session::save)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `map` method maps the input entries into `Serializable` instances by calling `session::save`, and then all you need to do is `collect` them to a `List`.